# How to find previous randomly generated number using Math.random in a setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, random, setinterval

I am generating a random number between 1 and 13. This works fine. What I want to do is not generate the same number as the immediate previous number.

```
function showRandomDotIcon() {
    var randomDot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
    console.log(randomDot);
}

setTimeout(showRandomDotIcon, 3500);
```

So something like:

```
if(randomDot == previousDot) {
    // skip to next number
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the last random value and check against it.

```js
function showRandomDotIcon() {
    var last;
    return function () {
        var randomDot;

        do {
            randomDot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
        } while (last === randomDot)
        last = randomDot;
        console.log(randomDot);
    };
}

setInterval(showRandomDotIcon(), 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, much appreciated.

Comment: Math note: skipping any repeats would make your event more predictable and less random. Imagine if you took that approach with a binary probabilistic outcome, like a coin toss.